# Azure Blob Storage logging not working at all

Tags: azure, logging, azure-blob-storage

I was trying to setup logging for a container and followed the documentation by enabling `Diagnostic settings (classic)`. However, while the `$logs` folder is created it simply stayed empty (for hours), while uploading and downloading files.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I enabled Read, Write, Delete and Delete data checkboxes under Logging and got some blobs in $logs container within half an hour. Which settings have you enabled?

Comment: @juunas actually I enabled all of them ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if someone else stumbles across this and after some back-and-forth with technical support, the problem seems to be related to some storage account settings. In particular with storage-account wide immutability settings.

What solved the problem for us was to disable immutability on the storage account level and to instead set it on the container level.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the logs may not appear in portal.Try checking **$logs from azure storage explorer.**

or they can be viewed through powershell or programmatically also.

Ensure that the Delete data check box is selected. Then, set the number of days that you would like log data to be retained .
Please check if retention policy is not set or set to 0,which may cause logs not to retain to show.

[image]

Reference :[Enable and manage Azure Storage Analytics logs (classic) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/manage-storage-analytics-logs?tabs=azure-portal)

Its also good to note that application logs for few apps may not provide logs in blob storage and only can be done in file system which is why they use  console.log('message') and console.error('message').

If we want to write Application logs to Azure blob storage ,firstly we need to enable Application log and configure blob storage for it on the Azure portal and keet its level to be verbose in some cases.

**Other references:**

1. [c# - ASP.NET Core Application Logs Not Written To Blob in Azure App
   Service - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46977129/asp-net-core-application-logs-not-written-to-blob-in-azure-app-service)
2. [logging - Azure WebApp Not Sending Application Logs to Blob Storage- Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44727570/azure-webapp-not-sending-application-logs-to-blob-storage)
3. [.net core - Azure WebJob not logging to blob storage - Stack
   Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46124856/azure-webjob-not-logging-to-blob-storage)